# Why Pandas gives me NAN values as an output in the whole table?

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a code to read two different .csv files. One of them has only one row, while the other has 24. In the file the data is separated by semicolons. I am writing a code where my new DataFrame takes values from both and make calculations. However, the calculations are done only for the first row of the table, all the other values are NAN. When I delete my first (one row csv file) DataFrame variable from the calculations, the values are working fine, none NAN value. I am suspecting that it is because the first file only has one row while the other has 24.

I am reading the files with this line:

```
#Step 1 - Reading the input file
static = pd.read_csv("Static_Data.csv", sep=';', na_values='(missing)')
dynamic = pd.read_csv("Dynamic_data.csv", sep=';', na_values='(missing)')
#dynamic = pd.read_csv("Dynamic_data.csv", sep=';', index_col=0, na_values='(missing)')
static
```

As a solution, I wonder, can I pass all the values from my first csv file to a constant variables so that this problem does not occur?

Myfirst csv file:
[image: First dataset]

The code snippet:

```
#Physical properties calculations
A_win = static['Height(m)'] * (static['Depth(m)'] + static['Length(m)'])*2*static['Awindow/Awall'] #Area of walls
A_wall =static['Height(m)'] * (static['Depth(m)'] + static['Length(m)'])*2*(1-static['Awindow/Awall'])*1.225 #Area of windows
t_ext = 20
m_dot = static['Air Changes/hour (h^-1)'] * static['Height(m)'] * (static['Depth(m)'] *static['Length(m)'])
c_p = 1.0021
u_wall = static['Uwalls(W/m2K)']                                                                    
#Calculation of energy flows inside the house
Energy_flows = pd.DataFrame(columns=[])
Energy_flows['Q_exterior'] = static['Uwalls(W/m2K)'] * A_wall * (dynamic['Temp'] - t_ext)/1000
Energy_flows['Q_interior'] = Energy_flows['Q_exterior'] 
Energy_flows['Q_windows'] = static['Uwalls(W/m2K)'] * A_wall * ( dynamic['Temp'] - t_ext)/1000
Energy_flows['Q_ventil'] = c_p * m_dot * (t_ext - dynamic['Temp'])/3600
Energy_flows['Q_intern'] = static['Qpeople(W)'] * dynamic['Occupation']/1000
Energy_flows['Q_solar'] = static['Window Solar Gain'] * static['Height(m)'] * (static['Depth(m)'] + static['Length(m)'])*static['Awindow/Awall']* dynamic['Rad (W/m^2)']/1000
Energy_flows['Q_envelope'] = Energy_flows['Q_exterior'] + Energy_flows['Q_interior'] + Energy_flows['Q_windows']
Energy_flows['Q_heating/cool'] = Energy_flows['Q_envelope'] + Energy_flows['Q_intern']  + Energy_flows['Q_ventil'] + Energy_flows['Q_solar'] 
Energy_flows
```

[image: Output]

Comment: You're multiplying `Series`, instead of `scalar * Series`

Comment: Would you be able to include `static.shape` and `dynamic.shape`?

Answer (score 0):

I think Joshua is right. To multiply with a scalar, use for example in the first calculation:

```
Energy_flows['Q_exterior'] = static['Uwalls(W/m2K)'][0] * A_wall * (dynamic['Temp'] - t_ext)/1000
```

You should specify the first index [0] of the static df column every time to make it a scaler.